# Transactions scope in WCF

Tags: wcf, transactions

I need to make call to a WCF service in a Transaction scope.
I have never tried transactions in WCF serivce.

Does anyone have experience in similar requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. The most important thing to keep in mind it that not all bindings support flowing transactions. The basicHttpBinding doesn't while the wsHttpbinding and the netTcpBindings do. Other than that I suggest a little more concrete questions.

Comment: Does the encoding(Text/Binary) effect the transaction behaviour of a WCF service?

Comment: No, the encoding is just a matter of how objects are wrapped up and shipped across the wire. The wsHttpBinding uses XML and the netTcpBinding use binary by default and both support transactions.